# pyserial's readline not able to read last some lines when the output has many lines

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to use pyserial to talk interact with a board and I am sending some commands and waiting for their reply am using this piece of code for waiting for => prompt

```
# Waits till it finds the => prompt
def s_uboot_prompt(ser):
    value = ""
    matcher = re.compile("\=\>")
    trymatcher = re.compile("try")
    while (not matcher.search(value)):
               if( trymatcher.search(value.strip()) ):
                        print "******* Command failure. Exiting ..... **********"
                        ser.write("boot\r")
                        ser.close()
                        sys.exit(0)

               value = ser.readline()
               print value
               time.sleep(2)
```

It works for all of the command but for one of the tftp commands where the output is really huge it fails to read the last couple of lines and the above code loops forever. is there any reason this is happening ? I am not able to think of any logical reason. Please note it's not able to read couple of last lines.

thnks

Comment: Have you tried without the regexp and print all the lines in a while loop?

Comment: I have not tried but the same code worked several times on the similar boards ! and it stopped working all of a sudden ! and i can try what you said, let me see what I will get

Comment: Is it really looping for ever? I'd imagine it is sitting on ser.readline() unless you set the default timeout to be something other then None. Also, does the last few lines of the huge output contain the `\n` char, this is what ser.readline() requires by default to return anything (unless it times out)?

Comment: i have a time out of 4 ! and yes it must have new line as it worked before and works on some other machine !